# Is it true that one can't raise both sides of an equation to a complex power?

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation

There are a lot of counterexamples. Am I missing something?
Question: Let $u,v,w \in \mathbb{C}$, does $v=w$ not always imply $v^u=w^u$?

Comment: if $u$ is not an  integer, and $v,w$ are not positive real numbers, there is no generally agreed meaning for your expressions. The heart of the problem is that the logarithm can not be extended in a single-valued way over the whole plane

Comment: It looks true.... What are some of the counterexamples?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Take $v = w = -1$ and $u = 1/3$, then the expressions $v^u$ and $w^u$ are both meaningless, since $-1$ has 3 distinct 3th roots, namely $-1, e^{\pi i / 3}, e^{-\pi i / 3}$.

Comment: I would dare to say that consequent approach to complex numbers were to state that every number has infinitely many copies ($ze^{2\pi ni}$) which behave synchronised under multiplication and addition but start play bad under non-integer exponention.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire I mean $e^{\pi i}=e^{3\pi i}$. Powered to $i$, we have $e^{-\pi} \neq e^{-3\pi}$.

Answer (score 1):

What? $v=w\Rightarrow v^u=w^u$ for all $u,v,w\in \mathbb C$. But it's not true that $v^u=w^u\implies v=w$, thats because the map $(-)^u$ is not alway injective, not only in $\mathbb C$ but also in $\mathbb R$! (i.e. if u=2 then (-1)^2=(1)^2 )